# I have encountered this Postgressql ERROR where I couldn't run a function in which case I have done Polymorphism on

Tags: postgresql-9.6

I'm trying to run code snippet

```
select total(new_schema.emp_pro) from new_schema.emp_pro;
```

with following error for some reason.

> ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "new_schema"

Comment: Use `total(emp_pro)` - assuming that your function expects a complete record as its input